# java / jsoup - retrieve language

Tags: java, string, return

i use jsoup to crawl content from specific website´s.

Example, meta-tags:

```
String meta_description = doc.select("meta[name=description]").first().attr("content");
```

What i need to crawl as well is the language, what i do:

```
String meta_language = doc.select("http-equiv").first().attr("content");
```

But what is thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Anybody could help with with this?

Greetings!

Comment: *Sigh* Which *exact* method call produces the NPE?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Operation.Operation.process_crawl(Operation_1.java:169)

Comment: Man, you're chaining multiple method calls and ask about a NPE which can happen when a) `doc` is null, b) the result of `select` is null, or c) the result of `first` is null. Should we speculate or can you simply check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String meta_language = doc.select("meta[name=http-equiv]").get(0).attr("content");
System.out.println("Meta description : " + meta_language);
```

However if you have a list of content in your meta tag then you can use this :

```
//get meta keyword content
String keywords = doc.select("meta[name=keywords]").first().attr("content");
System.out.println("Meta keyword : " + keywords);
```